# Execute Process Task Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Message

> Executed as user: ProxyID. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5548.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:05:02 AM  Error: 2015-05-11 11:12:25.65     Code: 0xC0029151     Source: Execute XML Generator Execute Process Task     Description: **In Executing "\Servername\path\app.exe" "" at ""**, The process **exit code was "-532459699" while the expected was "0"**.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:05:02 AM  Finished: 11:12:25 AM  Elapsed:  442.922 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am migrating a SSIS package (SQL Server 2005 version) to SQL Server 2012.
Have done all required connection changes and deployed to target. Created the job and executing it through the valid ProxyID.

In package, there are multiple dataflow tasks, batch file (gets executed by Process task) and at final a app.exe file (gets executed by Process task).

The above error is coming from the last .exe file (ProxyID has proper access to this file location).

Why the In Executing "`\\Servername\path\app.exe`" **"" at ""** is ?

What does mean The process exit code was "-532459699" while the expected was "0" ?

**EDIT:**

Note: This Package Running successfully from SSDT from Local Machine and also from the SQL Server Package Store (SSIS instance). Running from CMD.exe locally.

Getting failed from Agent JOB.

**EDIT 2**

While deploying the ssis package to the SSIS catalog of 2012 version.
The scheduled job is running for the same day the schedule was created, but the same is failing on the next day with the same error.

Requesting all your help.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

please check whether the package runs in 32-bit runtime mode or 64-bit runtime mode in BIDS by checking the Run64bitRuntime property of the project. Then, make sure the package runs in the same runtime mode in the SQL Server Agent job by checking or unchecking the “Use 32 bit runtime” option for the Execution options of the job step.

**If it is not the issue, please create another job that uses a CmdExec type job step to call the executable “\Servername\path\app.exe”. If this job also fails, the issue is actually occurs because of the issue between executable and SQL Server Agent rather than the SSIS package itself.**

Comment: Above 2 options are not working. What exactly is  the "issue between executable and SQL Server Agent rather than the SSIS package itself"? There is no issue with the package itself.